# how use a structure in a unaligned buffer

Tags: c, gcc, network-programming, arm, strict-aliasing

In my network app, in the received buffer, I want to use an offset as a pointer to a known struct.
Copying every field of the structure with memcpy() 2 times (rx/tx) is heavy.
I know that my gcc 4.7.2 (option: -O3) on cortex-a8, do memcpy(&a,&buff,4) in 1 instruction unaligned.
So, he can access to unaligned int.
Assume that it could have lot of struct, or big struct.
What's the best way to do it?

```
struct __attribute__ ((__packed__)) msg_struct {
  int a;  //0 offset
  char b; //4 offset
  int c;  //5 offset
  int d[100];  //9 offset
}

char buff[1000];// [0]:header_size [1-header_size]:header [header_size+1]msg_struct

func() {
  struct msg_struct *msg;
  recv ((void *)buff, sizeof(buff));
  msg=buff+header_size; // so, it is unaligned.
  ...
    // some work like:
    int valueRcv=msg->c;
  //or modify buff before send 
  msg->c=12;

  send(buff,sizeof(buff));
}
```

Comment: Does this work with `buff` being an array of `int`s? Adding `header_size` will bring your pointer to a very wrong place.

Comment: Make sure you understand how pointer arithmetic works.

Comment: Compiler options? Unless you've taken action to cause the compiler to pack this structure, it will use natural alignment for the fields - which is probably not what you want.

Comment: You shouldn't be using language- and compiler- and hardware-dependent data structures as network protocols in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

To instruct GCC to use an alignment of one byte for a structure and its members, use the GCC `packed` attribute, shown on [this page](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Type-Attributes.html#Type-Attributes). In your code, change:

```
struct msg_struct {…}
```

to:

```
struct __attribute__ ((__packed__)) msg_struct {…}
```

You will also need to correct the pointer arithmetic. Adding `header_size` to `buff` adds the distance of 100 `int` objects, because `buff` is a pointer to `int`. You should likely maintain `buff` as an array of `unsigned char` rather than `int`.

Comment: yes, sorry, my question is centered on how accès to the the structure field in the recieved buffer ? like:  int valueRcv=msg->c; and msg->c=12;

Comment: @DavidBonnin: Your code already contains such accesses. You need to correct the pointer arithmetic so that `msg` is correctly calculated with `unsigned char` rather than `int`.